# Cursor Infinite Loop before Return Keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have this code snippet in my stored procedure

```
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR into @id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    IF @Res == NULL
    BEGIN 
        SET @Var = false
        RETURN;
    END
    
    --some other code here
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR into @id
    END
```

If for example the variable @Res is NULL and the variable @Var is set to `FALSE` then the `RETURN` keyword is called, will it cause an infinite loop if I don't call the FETCH NEXT before the RETURN keyword?

UPDATE 1: ok, so apparently when it enters the if-else block, and the control proceeds to the RETURN block, the control goes out of the WHILE loop. My goal is for the loop to continue after setting the @Var variable.

UPDATE 2: Accepted Gordon Linoff's answer about checking for null values.

Comment: Why are you using a `CURSOR` in the first place would be by question. SQL is a Query Language, not a programming language; it excels at set-based methods not iterative ones. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Larnu I understand your point about using cursors but I am currently required to use one. And I need to understand its behavior if the FETCH NEXT keyword isn't called before the RETURN keyword.

Comment: Seems like something you can easily test yourself

Comment: *"I am currently required to use one."* why? They are *almost* always misused (for example, creating every date in a given period, cumulative aggregates, running the same task for multiple tables, etc). If you're worried about things like infinite loops, then don't use a `CURSOR` and use a set-based method. Then you can't have any, as you're code doesn't loop (and is probably far more efficient).

Comment: It all depends on your @@FETCH_STATUS - Like HoneyBadger writes. Its quite simple to test your self

Comment: == is not a valid tsql operator. You should review the documentation for **RETURN** as well as **BREAK** (and perhaps **CONTINUE**) since it seems BREAK is what you want. It would be far better to simply run the code and see the result yourself - you will learn more by doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic:

```
IF @Res == NULL
```

does not do what you expect.  Almost any comparison to `NULL` returns `NULL` -- which is treated as false.

The correct logic is:

```
IF @Res IS NULL
```

That said, you should probably be avoiding cursors in your code.  And you should learn about `NULL` values in SQL.